# Combine group_by and distinct

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with two variables `id.x` and `id.y` whose combination uniquely identifies each row but are repeated many times in the dataset.

I would like to use `dplyr` to `group_by` `id.x` such that each `id.x` is matched with a distinct `id.y`.

**edit** edited example to highlight the differing number of `unique` `id.x.` and `id.y`

An example:

```
  id.x id.y
    a    o
    a    p
    a    q
    c    o
    c    p
    c    q
```

Would return:

```
 id.x id.y
    a    o
    c    q
```

dput for example:

```
structure(list(id.x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"c"), class = "factor"), id.y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("o", "p", "q"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id.x", 
"id.y"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*edit* If my desired result could be accomplished without the use of `group_by` or `distinct` that is fine too! I also use `data.table`, and a `data.table` solution would be fine.

Comment: How do you want want the 'matches' to be defined?  There is no 'distinct' call that would create your desired result.

Comment: I'd like the matches to be defined in such a way that there are the maximum amount of `distinct` `id.x` and `id.y` in the final `data.frame` subject to `length(unique(id.x))==length(unique(id.y))==nrow(data.frame)`. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Not sure, but how about `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, unique)]` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks! that works in my test data, but in my original data there are less id.x's than id.y's and so that function returns:
`1: In as.data.table.list(jval) :
  Item 1 is of size 1395 but maximum size is 10525 (recycled leaving a remainder of 760 items)`

Comment: i will edit the original question to make this clear

Comment: So where did `p` go? How did you decide to exclude it in particular?

Comment: Good question. I guess what I am really trying to do is select a subset of the id.y that each correspond to a unique id.x. I originally joined on a number of covariates, and now I'd like to select two groups of equal size from the merge, maximizing the number of unique id.x and id.y.

Comment: Maybe `setDT(df)[, list(unique(id.x), unique(id.y)[1:uniqueN(id.x)])]` then... (`uniqueN` is from the devel version on GH). You can replace it with `length(unique(id.x))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg using `uniqueN` has the possibility of returning a combination that is not part of the original data.  If `df[5,2]<-"r"` it will still return `a o` and `c p` even though `c p` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
df %>% filter(dense_rank(id.x)==dense_rank(id.y))
```

which returns

```
  id.x id.y
1    a    o
2    c    p
```